# Apple codesign where is the signature?

Tags: codesign

I want to learn using Apple OSX command `codesign`.

I was able to sign an executable, and I was able to run `codesign --verbose -dv <file>` to verify it. But I used `md5` command on the file and the hash remains the same before it got signed. Where is the signature been written to???